# Blazor CS0103: "The name 'lines' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

Hello stackoverflow community, I am getting error CS0103 I've searched google but couldn't find an answer sorry if this is a bad question I'm new with Blazor.

I'm Trying to make a table from a comma seperated file.

```
@page "/fetchdata"


<PageTitle>Keyword analytics</PageTitle>

@using BlazorApp.Data


<h1>Keyword Analytics</h1>

 <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Keyword</th>
                <th>Volume</th>
                <th>Competition</th>
                <th>Results</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@line[0]</td>
                    <td>@line[1]</td>
                    <td>@line[2]</td>
                    <td>@line[3]</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>


@code
{

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    { 
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\someone\Desktop\max\BlazorApp\Something.txt");

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            line.Split(';');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `lines` inside a method, so it is scoped to that method.

```
@code
{
    string[] lines = Array.Empty<string>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    { 
        lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\ra1n\Desktop\max\BlazorApp\SemRUSH.txt");

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            line.Split(';'); // This does not do anything except waste CPU
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, and I didn't notice that I fixed it with 
                    <td>@line.Split(";")[0]</td>
                    <td>@line.Split(";")[1]</td>...